# Possible Installation locations of a minifilter driver

Tags: windows, driver, inf, minifilter

The attributes of a MiniFilter Driver (and for that matter, any Driver), are [encapsulated in an .INF file](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ifs/creating-an-inf-file-for-a-minifilter-driver). One of the sections in the .INF file is the DestinationDirs section, which according to Microsoft is optional.
Most examples I have seen use value 12 (or 11).
11 - \Windows\System32\
12 - \Windows\System32\Drivers

What are the other possible values of

```
MiniFilter.DriverFiles
```

and which option can be used to install a MiniFilter Driver in a custom path (i.e. *"c:\myfolder\"*)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use any of [defined DirIds](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/install/using-dirids). To use an arbitrary path, specify -1 and the path after the comma.

But it is not recommended to place a filesystem-related driver to a directory other than System32\drivers. At the early boot time, only few system directories can be accessible to the loader, and your filter may not be loaded. It may prevent the system from initializing properly.

Comment: You write “At early boot time, only few system directories can be accessible”, can you elaborate and provide a reference to such information?

Comment: NT systems boot from partitions, not from drive letters (see BCD entries or boot.ini for older systems). At the early boot time, there are no drive letters, the appropriate symlinks are created later. Drivers being loaded at boot time have no paths, only file names, the loader directly finds them in System32\drivers. If a filter driver module is specified by a letter-based path, the letter is not guaranteed to be known when the appropriate FS is initialized.

Comment: Well the only option other then the Drivers folder would be for some developers installing the driver in the same location as the .inf file and possibly any software using the driver. In other words, placing the driver in the current path when driver was installed. Do you think its impossible for auto start drivers?

Comment: For auto-start drivers, it is possible in almost all cases. In most cases, it is possible for boot-start drivers too, but you should clearly understand when your driver may be loaded. If it is guaranteed to load after full system initialization (for example, filters only non-system drives), you can place it where you want.